# Different ways to define a constant in a namespace

Tags: php, namespaces, constants

There seems to be different ways to put constants in a namespace, and selected ways to display them depending on how they are defined.

**Brief Overview:**
If I define a constant and use `namespace user;` I cannot use `\user\CONSTANT` to later access it.
If define a constant with the namespace name, e.g. `define('user\USERNAME', 'James')`, I don't need to use `namespace user;` and can access the constant in two ways - using the `namespace user;` and `user\USERNAME`.

### EXAMPLES:

Note:
All examples include the entire code used in the test file (if code from a previous example is missing it's because it wasn't used in the new test)

**define.php**

```
namespace user;
define('USERNAME', 'James');
include 'display.php';
```

**display.php**

```
namespace user;
echo USERNAME; // Displays "James"

// This will NOT work (Fatal error: Undefined constant)
echo \user\USERNAME;
```

However I can set the constant in the namespace another way:
**define.php**

```
define('user\USERNAME', 'James');
include 'display.php';
```

And now I have TWO ways to display the constant:

**display.php**

```
namespace user;
echo USERNAME; // Displays "James"
```

**AND**

**display.php**

```
echo \user\USERNAME; // Displays "James"
```

*Both* display "James" just fine.

### My Question

I'm not asking what *you* prefer etc, but is there a problem with using either of these methods?
Is one better due to performance (presume micro secs so pointless), or perhaps does one method cause issues somewhere else in PHP?

I know not explicitly setting the namespace like `namespace user;` means I don't get anything else in that file set to the namespace, which would be ok if I only want constant(s) in the namespace.

Is this simply a choice depending on scenario, or is one method bad for some reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the second variant, if you want to define the constant in the namespace only. so

```
define('user\USERNAME', 'James');
```

is not just the preferred syntax, it is the only correct syntax. if you are writing

```
define('USERNAME', 'James');
```

then you are defining a **GLOBAL CONST** even if your define call is done within the user namespace. So obviously this would work, because you can access the value from within the namespace - but also from within any namespace, so not what you wanted :)

Comment: Ahh you are correct - I did not test for just echoing global constant. So basically my very first example, I don't even need `namespace user;` in the `define.php`. Actually, I should have seen that :( cheers